# Webview app for windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, webview

I recently had to create an Android app for work, it was a simple app with a webview that directs you to the website where our app was running. Now I have to do the same thing for windows, I've been searching now for 2 days but I can't seem to find anything that would really help me, I am a node.js developer and have never used c# or visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear if you want to do this for Windows desktop or Windows mobile.

For both Desktop and mobile you can use either the built in Winforms [Webbrowser component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) or the 3PP open source [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/)

The CefSharp website has some quick guides to get your started.
And [this is a simple example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser) for the built in control on winforms

For mobile you can use the built in [Webbrowser component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx) for mobile

Comment: It's for windows mobile, but probably wasn't the best way to describe my problem, but I'm getting closer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @KylevanTil  I  have come down this way looking for the solution. I need something similar, I want to allow user to login via github credentials in my app by opening git webview. Any guidance help would be highly appreciated.